# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 C++ Circular Reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, circular-reference

I have a question to ask. Is it possible for projects to reference each other under a same solution?

For example, both projects A and B have their own exported functions. Project A references Project B and Project B references Project A. Both projects needed to access the exported functions from each other.

Technically, would it be possible?

Comment: Do you mean just from the code or from the solution? i.e. project dependencies? If the latter then no, you will observe that you cannot introduce a project dependency via the latter method. From the project menu

Comment: Not within VisualStudio no but you can at the import level although it's somewhat difficult and usually much more effort than it's worth. For instance you can actually export functions from an EXE that DLL's can link to when loaded. This gives your DLL's immediate access to functionality within the EXE without a lot of setup and manually initialization. Look into creating .DEF files and generating import libraries (LIB) from them. Not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: I just tried this and the dependant project is greyed out, when you try this a pop up dialog tells you `This dependency cannot be added because it will create a circular dependency`

Comment: Which project will be built first?

Comment: @EdChum I am actually trying to include the .lib file through the project properties, under Linker > Input. I'm aware that if I add references, they won't allow me to.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I will look into creating .DEF files. However, I guess I will go with the option of putting the relevant exported functions as another DLL and using Project A and B to reference to it. Thank you.

Comment: Putting all common code in a third is certainly your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is possible, but it has problems.

When you build the 2 DLLs, DLL A requires lib file of B, B requires lib file of A.

Here're how we do it: First project A doesn't depend on B, only B depends on A. A exports 2 functions funcA1 and funcA2, while we can build DLL A, then we can build B  and generate B.lib. As we have the file B.lib, then we can let A depends on B and add code to use the exported functions from B. This was how we created Circular Reference in my real life project.

The problem is: when you clean up all lib files and do a rebuilt, you can't. I'm not a fan of this, instead of creating circular reference, we should put the related functions into another DLL.

Comment: Actually one way around that is to create a third project (Project C) that uses custom build commands to create an import library from a DEF file. Then you make Project A and Project B dependent on Project C. Then the import libraries are built before at the correct time.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for the explanation. I do foresee circular references issues when doing a rebuilt. They will not allow this. I'm taking the suggestion to put the related functions into another DLL (Project C) with Project A and B referencing to C instead.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, this is impossible. If two projects A and B reference each other, they would be the same project - it is unclear what kind of project would make this structure necessary.